# Bandpass Filter in Python for Image Processing

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, filtering

I have a noisy dataset (a stack of images) which films dim particles moving about some really bright artefacts (which are immobilized). I would like to somehow remove the immobilized artefacts from the images by applying some sort of bandpass filter wherein only pixels within a specific range are converted to white pixels and everything else is masked black. Can someone point me in the right direction, on how to do this in `Python/Open-CV`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pretty sure ```open cv``` produces ```numpy``` arrays. If You could figure out a threshold for the color space, you can use the threshold with Boolean indexing of the ```numpy``` array to replace or change the offending pixel's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for: http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html

Specificially look at the "Examining a specific data range"
This will allow you to easily clip the image.